# How to build jar file for Spring Boot project in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have three *.properties files. When I switch between these files in the studio everything works as expected. But when I build a jar file, I think it can't find the properties file, it's visible on port 8080. Although in the settings I specified 8090 (dev) or 5000 (prod). How to solve this problem. Can someone tell me how to properly assemble a jar file?

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

application-dev.properties

```
# ---- Server ----
server.port=8090
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
# ---- Mail ----
spring.mail.username=************@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=************
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
# ---- Postgres ----
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/endpoint
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# ---- Firebase ----
app.firebase.config=serviceAccountKey.json
```

application-prod.properties

```
# ---- Server ----
server.port=5000
server.error.include-stacktrace=never
# ---- Mail ----
spring.mail.username=************@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=************
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
# ---- Postgres ----
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/endpoint
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# ---- Firebase ----
app.firebase.config=serviceAccountKey.json
```

Production in Intellij
[image: Prod]

Development in Intellij
[image]

Out jar
[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you building the jar? Have you defined the Spring Boot plugin in your gradle build file.

Comment: Yes, I have:
plugins {
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.6'
 id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
 id 'java'
}

Build jar: File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Add ->Jar/From modules and dependencies... -> next, I select <all modules>, specify <main class> and select  <copy to the output directory and link via manifest>, because if I select <extract to the target JAR> and specify META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in resources, I get no manifest class when run jar with console

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, as that is totally unreadable. Instead edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

In prod, you are running the application wihtout setting an active profile, and hence it will use the settings from `application.properties` only:
[image]

Try to start your application in prod with the prod-profile e.g

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar`